# Completion handler called before data loads

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, grand-central-dispatch

How do I prevent a completion handler from being called until data is loaded from firebase in the following code?

My issue:
Completion is called before any users are appended to the array of users. How do I call `completion` only after `users` actually has users appended to it?

Do I have to use Grand Central Dispatch?

Bonus points if you can explain this to me like I'm 5 yrs. old, so I can stop facing this issue.

```
class func fetchFavorites(userId: String, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Swift.Void) {
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    let favRef = Database.database().reference().child("favorites").child(userId)

    favRef.observe(.value) { snap in
        var users: [User] = []
        for item in snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            userRef.child(item.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                    let newUser = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                    users.append(newUser)
                }
            }
        }
        completion(users)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `completion()` is called on the `favRef.observe(.value){}` in an async way, that's okay, but `userRef.child(item.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value){}` is also async, that's your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure I follow. Can you clarify in code?

Answer (score 2):

You have two nested async functions, namely `favRef.observe` and `userRef.child().observeSingleEvent(of:)`, hence the issue is that `completion` is called in the outer closure before all async calls updating the users could finish execution.

You can solve this issue by using a `DispatchGroup` and only calling `completion` once all async method calls finished execution in the loop. This can be achieved by adding all async calls to the `DispatchGroup`, then calling `completion` inside a `group.notify` call.

```
class func fetchFavorites(userId: String, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Swift.Void) {
    let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    let favRef = Database.database().reference().child("favorites").child(userId)
    let usersGroup = DispatchGroup()

    favRef.observe(.value) { snap in
        var users: [User] = []
        for item in snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            usersGroup.enter()
            userRef.child(item.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                    let newUser = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                    users.append(newUser)
                }
                usersGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        usersGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()){
            completion(users)
        }
    }
}
```